# Project a Query onto an anonymous Dictionary<string,int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary, ienumerable

I am trying to check if an entity in the database has any foreign key relations, so that I can inform the user the entity can or cannot be deleted.

I understand this can be done in a rolled back transaction, however I would like to inform the user how many references and where they are to assist in their decision to delete the entity.

I am trying to avoid loading the entire navigation collection into memory to get this data as it may be large. So, in light of this, I can formulate this simple query to firstly determine if there are any references:

```
private bool CanDeleteComponent(int compId)
{
    var query = _Context.Components.Where(c => c.ComponentID == compId)
        .Select(comp => new
        {
            References = comp.Incidents.Any() &&
            comp.Drawings.Any() &&
            comp.Documents.Any() &&
            comp.Tasks.Any() &&
            comp.Images.Any() &&
            comp.Instructions.Any()
        });
    var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)
    {
        return !result.References;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This performs a series of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLE> WHERE...` queries.

Now, I would like to provide some further information on the number of references. Ideally I would like to return a Dictionary with the referenced data's name, and the associated count. This way I can loop through the result, rather than access individual properties of an anonymous type. However, what I have tried results in an exception:

```
var query = _Context.Components.Where(c => c.ComponentID == compId)
        .Select(comp => new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {"Events", comp.Incidents.Count()},
            {"Drawings", comp.Drawings.Count()},
            {"Documents", comp.Documents.Count()},
            {"Tasks", comp.Tasks.Count()},
            {"Images", comp.Images.Count()},
            {"Instructions", comp.Instructions.Count()},
        });
    var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
    return query.Any(fk => fk.Value > 0);
```

The exception that is raised is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
Additional information: Only list initializer items with a single element are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Is there any way around this, such that I can return some sort of IEnumerable rather than an anonymous type?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I currently have lazy loading disabled on my context. If there is a solution without turning Lazy loading on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build a `Dictionary<K,V>` in the `SELECT` statement, that's why you get `System.NotSupportedException`. You can get the single `Component` first by query, and build the dictionary in the memory.

```
var comp = _Context.Components.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ComponentID == compId);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "Events", comp.Incidents.Count()},
    { "Drawings", comp.Drawings.Count()},
    { "Documents", comp.Documents.Count()},
    { "Tasks", comp.Tasks.Count()},
    { "Images", comp.Images.Count()},
    { "Instructions", comp.Instructions.Count()}
};
```

**EDIT** If you are not using lazy loading, you can explicitly `.Include` the properties in the query:

```
var comp = _Context.Components
    .Include(c => c.Incidents)
    ...
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ComponentID == compId);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see this would work if i had LazyLoadingEnabled = true. Is there any way with it turned off?

Comment: thanks but this now loads all navigation data, which could be quite large and memory intensive which is what i am trying to avoid. The ultimate goal is to only execute the `SELECT COUNT()` queries for each FK table

Comment: @Simon Try `.Where(xxx).Select(comp => new
            {
                Events = comp.Incidents.Count,
                Drawings = comp.Drawings.Count,
                Document = comp.Documents.Count,
                Tasks = comp.Tasks.Count,
                Images = comp.Images.Count,
                Instructions = comp.Instructions.Count
            }).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks Danny, doesn't seem like there is a way to do it all in the query, so this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way around this, such that I can return some sort of IEnumerable rather than an anonymous type?

Actually there is, although I'm not sure you'll like the generated SQL (compared to the one using anonymous type).

```
var query = _Context.Components.Where(c => c.ComponentID == compId)
    .SelectMany(comp => new []
    {
        new { Key = "Events", Value = comp.Incidents.Count() },
        new { Key = "Drawings", Value = comp.Drawings.Count() },
        new { Key = "Documents", Value = comp.Documents.Count() },
        new { Key = "Tasks", Value = comp.Tasks.Count() },
        new { Key = "Images", Value = comp.Images.Count() },
        new { Key = "Instructions", Value = comp.Instructions.Count() },
     }.ToList());

var result = query.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);

return query.Any(fk => fk.Value > 0);
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  For starters, the example doesn't compile for me until I put `new` before each anonymous object.  Second, I am getting the error `The array type '<>f__AnonymousType1'2[System.String,System.Int32][]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[<>f__AnonymousType1'2[System.String,System.Int32]]' instead.`

Comment: @erdomke You are right about `new` before each array element. What about exception you are getting, it's happening if you use `Select` instead of `SelectMany`. Adding `ToList()` at the end makes it work in both `Select` and `SelectMany` - see the update. EF is strange monster :)

Comment: You are correct that I managed to gloss over your use of SelectMany.  The example now works for me, but only if I omit your newly added ToList().  With the ToList, I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[<>f__AnonymousType1'2[System.String,System.Int32]] ToList[<>f__AnonymousType1'2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[<>f__AnonymousType1'2[System.String,System.Int32]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`  Thanks for the help!